# Recurrence relation for right-angled triangles stuck-together

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics, triangles

Given the image:
[image]

and that $x_0 = 1, y_0=0$ and $\text{angles} \space θ_i
, i = 1, 2, 3, · · ·$ can be arbitrarily picked.

How can I derive a recurrence relationship for $x_{n+1}$ and $x_n$?

I actually know what the relationship is, however, don't know how to derive it.

Although it is obvious to see that $x_0 = x_1$

so for $n = 0$

We have $x_{1} = x_{0}+0 $

The recurrence relations are

$x_{n+1}=x_n−y_ntan(θ_{n+1})$

and

$y_{n+1}=y_n+x_ntan(θ_{n+1})$
But I can't get the derivation.

[image]

I tried taking some arbitrary right angle triangle and constructing two vectors.

$\mathop r_{\sim}  = \langle x_n,y_n \rangle $

and a vector perpendicular to $\mathop r_\sim$, $\mathop d_{\sim} = \langle a,b\rangle$ such that

$\mathop r_{\sim} \cdot \mathop d_{\sim} = 0 $

Then we can let construct a unit vector for $\mathop d_\sim$ and eventually construct a line through a point?

Comment: Hint: Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I can't think of how and where, especially when dealing with the unknowns

Comment: Are you familiar with rotation matrices?

Comment: This is the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207240/x-y-coordinates-from-gluing-together-a-sequence-of-right-triangles-with-arbitr isn't it?

Comment: Isn't it???????

Comment: haha, yes it is @GerryMyerson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P_i = (x_i,y_i)$, then $P_{n+1}$ is obtained by rotating $P_n$ about the origin by angle $\theta_{n+1}$, and scaling by a factor of $\frac{|OP_{n+1}|}{|OP_n|} = \sec\theta_{n+1}$. Using a rotation matrix, we can write

$$P_{n+1} \;=\; \sec\theta_{n+1}\;\left[\begin{array}
 \;\cos\theta_{n+1} & -\sin\theta_{n+1} \\
 \sin\theta_{n+1} & \phantom{-}\cos\theta_{n+1}
\end{array}\right]\;P_n \;=\; \left[\begin{array}{cc}
 \;1 & -\tan\theta_{n+1} \\
 \tan\theta_{n+1} & 1
\end{array}\right]\;P_n$$

Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
x_{n+1} &= x_n - y_n\tan\theta_{n+1} \\
y_{n+1} &= x_n \tan\theta_{n+1} + y_n
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

This is a generalization of the
"Spiral of Theodorus"
which is discussed in many places.
Here is the obvious one:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_of_Theodorus

Using the methods there
as a guide.

(I guess this should be a comment 
rather than an answer -
I was too impulsive.)

Comment: Thanks for the link marty, although I am not able to see anything which may help me in my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative formulation, and this also serves to illustrate that sometimes a different notation makes things appear simpler. First, define
$$\delta x_n=x_{n+1}-x_n$$
$$\delta y_n=y_{n+1}-y_n$$
Now. from the figure, we have 
$$\tan^2 {\theta_{n+1}}=\frac{(x_{n+1}-x_n)^2+(y_{n+1}-y_n)^2}{x_n^2+y_n^2}$$
$$\tan^2 {\theta_{n+1}}=\frac{\delta x_n^2+\delta y_n^2}{x_n^2+y_n^2}$$
Now using the fact that the square of the hypotenuse of a right triangle is the sum of squares of the bases, we get
$$(x_n^2+y_n^2)+(\delta x_n^2+\delta y_n^2) = (x_n+\delta x_n)^2 + (y_n+\delta y_n)^2$$
Which simplifies to 
$$x_n\delta x_n+y_n\delta y_n=0$$
From here, we get $\delta y_n$ in terms of $\delta x_n$, $x_n$ and $y_n$. Plugging this back into the first equation, you get exactly the recurrences you're looking for.

Comment: Substituting $x_n \delta x_n + y_n \delta y_n = 0$

we get $y_{n+1}  = y_n - \frac{x_n}{y_n}(x_{n+1} - x_n)$

How does this become 
$y_{n+1}  = y_n + x_n \tan(\theta_{n+1})$ ?

Comment: Use the first equation, that involves the square of $\tan {\theta_{n}}$. That works out to what your result states.

Comment: So am I subbing $x_n \delta x_n + y_n \delta y_n$ into the $\tan ^2(\theta_{n+1})$ equation?

Comment: No, you write $\delta y_n=-\frac{x_n \delta x_n}{y_n}$, and sub this value of $\delta y_n$ into the first equation involving the tan.

Comment: Thanks bolt, I will try this now

Comment: My typos in tags {2,3} noticed after 2 months!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not well-posed. There are several solutions to the given problem depending on discretization choice. One more condition is needed to solve the finite "spiral". I am assuming that the real aim here is to find the spiral which is described by the tip of rotating vector.

An extreme choice of discretization is when the different $(x_i,y_i),(x_{i+1},y_{i+1}) $ are spaced  infinitesimally close to each respecting the given relations among the discrete increments.

We have the same scenario that marks difference between *finite difference calculus* and the *infinitesimal calculus*.

Eliminating $ \tan \theta_{n+1}$ between the two given relations which is quite a straight forward thing,

$$ \dfrac{y_{n+1} - y_n}{x_{n+1} - x_n}=-  \dfrac{x_n}{y_n} \tag{1}$$

$$ \dfrac{\Delta y} {\Delta x}=-  \dfrac{x}{y}\tag{2} $$

which passes to the limit by differential calculus:

$$ \dfrac{d y} {d x}=-  \dfrac{x}{y} \rightarrow  x \;{d x} + y\;{d y}=0 \tag{3} $$

which integrates to $$ x^2 + y^2 = R^2 \tag{4} $$ where R depends on starting $ x_i,y_i $ values, $ x_i^2 + y_i^2 = R^2 $; if $y_i=0$ ,then $ x_i = R.$

It is a Circle, the limiting case among a set of infinite solutions.