# (x,y) coordinates from gluing together a sequence of right triangles with arbitrary angles

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, computational-mathematics

I have been scratching my head all day over this question for one of my assignments. I haven't made any progress and I'm at the point of giving up. Here's what I need help with.

---

Start by gluing together a sequence of right angled triangles as shown in the
following diagram.
[image]

The angles $\theta_i$, $i = 1, 2, 3, \dots$ can be freely chosen. This construction produces a sequence of points $(x,y)_n$ in the plane. Show that
\begin{align}
x_{n+1} &= x_n - y_n \tan \theta_{n+1} \tag{1} \\
y_{n+1} &= y_n + x_n \tan \theta_{n+1} \tag{2}
\end{align}

---

I have no idea how to even begin to work this out. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tangent equals opposite over adjacent. Opposite is length of line segment joining $n+1$th point to $n$th point, adjacent is length of line segment joining origin to $n$ point. Plug in the formulas, see what comes out.

Comment: Making any progress?

Comment: This is the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207134/recurrence-relation-for-right-angled-triangles-stuck-together isn't it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.

Answer (score 1):

To your picture, I have added some extras as hint. Hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: Hey your picture is quite helpful in making me understand. However, I have problems with trying to show that those angles you've labeled are equal to $\theta_{n+1}$. Could you show me how to prove it?

Comment: @azza_075 Let work backward. By eliminating $\tan \theta_{n + 1}$ from (1) and (2), we have $\frac {-(x_{n+1} – x_n)}{y_{n+1}– y_n} = \frac {y_n}{x_n}$. By letting $n = 0$, we have $\frac {-(x_{1} – x_0)}{y_{1}– y_0} = \frac {y_0}{x_0}$. Comparing each ratio with the actual figure and see how they are related to $\theta$. Note: there is a minus sign in between y(n+1)  and y(n) but cannot be sohow clearly in the comment.